# MariaDB how to deal with already system-versioned tables

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am using MariaDB and part of my schema management I have multiple SQL files that
are applied to the database.

I have one SQL file that fails because system versioning is already been applied.

Can one write the SQL in a safer way and not to fail when system versioning has already been applied to a table.

Here is my example failing SQL:

```
alter IGNORE table my_table_name add system versioning;
```

How can one change this to be something to only apply system versioning if the table does not
have system versioning; or alternatively just ignore if system versioning has already been applied.